# How geotiff converted to 3d model?

Tags: convert, geotiff-tiff, modelling, 3d-model, blendergis

I have image .tiff (format geotiff). How I can convert the image to 3d model (terrain)? Blender or world machine can do it?

Comment: Welcome. Please edit your question to include what you have already tried and any errors you are receiving/the results you expect vs. the results you are receiving.  For more guidance, please take the tour here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE Art. Please update your question to include pertinent details such as an introduction to your problem and what software you are using and/or hope to be using.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search on the internet, I found that there are many tutorials available to show how to import raster DEM in Blender:

1. [How to Download and Import a Real World Terrain in blender (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7YhIzQ_7DE)
2. [BLENDER TUTORIAL](https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/blender-tutorial/)
3. [Preparing Your DEM](http://katiekowalsky.me/posts/2015/12/03/Preparing-DEM.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try QGIS 3j's plugin.

See:

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Qgis2threejs/